# Pycharm stills shows the old name after renaming a .py file. How to fix this?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2. I find that after renaming a file, if I run the current file. Pycharm still shows the original name.

[image: See picture here]

The original file name is **temp.py**, and later I change its name to **read_class_scores.py**. When I want to run it by right click of the mouse, pycharm still shows the name **temp**, not the new name.

I tried to delete the **.idea** folder under my project and restart Pycharm. But that has no effect. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: How are you renaming the file? When I right click refactor / rename `(Shift + F6)` the name of the file is updated for the right click is updated however the file name next to the play button at the top is not

Comment: @Kai, I renamed the file via `Refactor-->rename` option by right click on the file.

Comment: Interesting, I just checked it looks like my MacBook has the same issue as you, but the older version of pycharm on Windows 10 seems to update the name after refactoring. I guess it could be a bug & you could always raise a bug report with Jetbrains if no one has a real solution. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/reporting-issues-and-sharing-your-feedback.html

Comment: @Kai, I am not sure if it is really a bug or rather a feature :). Anyway, I will report it to jetbrains.

Comment: @Kai, I have get feedback from jetbrain. Turns out that it is not a bug. See my answer for how to fix this if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reporting [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24414) to JetBrains, I get their feedback that this is not bug but rather a feature.

Two methods can be used to remedy this inconsistency after renaming a `.py` file under the current project. You can delete the configuration of current file after renaming.

Another workaround is that you can first delete all configuration files and set 'Temporary configuration limit' to 0 in the "Run/Debug Configurations" window.

[image: see picture here]

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, but commenting on every post here is a bit excessive.

Comment: I do not know if comment to one user can be seen by all users.

Comment: It can not always be seen by all users, but you can use the `@` username to make sure those you want to know will see it.

Comment: you mean I can @ users in my post? But @ does not seem to work when I try to use it in my post.

Comment: @user in a comment, thus one comment can contact multiple people.

Answer (score 4):

What you seeing is likely the *Run Configuration* not the filename.  You will need to edit the configuration:

[image]

Check it out ([here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations.html))

Answer (score 0):

This is because the PyCharm would use the run file name as the default run configuration name if you didn't name it manually, you could either rename it as Rauch said, or just use the same configuration file to run it.

As far as I've experienced, it wouldn't have any impact on your project.

Comment: yes, that doesn't cause any real problem. But I would prefer that the config file name can be automatically updated once the python file's name is changed. The name inconsistency causes confusion for beginners like me.

Comment: actually, usually I'd use one configuration for one project, so no matter how you change the file name, as if you keep the project name consistency, you could avoid this trouble. BTW, you shouldn't think that the configuration goes with file, but should with project.....

Comment: @chrishcheng021, When I add a new py file and run it. It seem that a new config file is automatically generated.

Comment: @jdhao Actually I wonder, if you add a new py file in your python project,why would you run it alone? I mean, shouldn't a python project only have one entrance and every py file should just be a module of it?

Comment: @chrischeeng021, no, that is not the case. It is a big project, I write some utility script to generate some result for further analysis. So it is not a kind of package that only has one entrance.